# People Detection Algorithm

Tags: ros, nite

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to modify the people detection algorithm that openni_kinect uses? I am currently making the kinect save the calibration data and load it immediately when it finds a "person". However, it detects many things that are not people and do not look like people, such as poles and tables. Is the people detection part of the code completely closed source, or can I access it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10914/people-detection-algorithm/) by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2011-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The NITE software for people detection is proprietary; PrimeSense has not released its source code, although the device driver and OpenNI middleware layer are fully open source.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1